Half-Life Conundrum: Single atom vs group. Where did the 4 seconds Go?
I asked this question an AI so as not to spam this group. It failed and I am certainly still confused.
Here is a severe condensation of the conversation:
ME: If I had a group of 16 atoms each with a half-life of 1-second, how long for it to decay from 16 to 0?
AI: ~ 5-seconds.
ME: What if I split the atoms into 2 bags of 8 each. How long would it take for them to decay to 0 each?
AI: Each bag would take 4 seconds to reach 0. The total for the 2 bags is 4 seconds.
ME: What if there were only 1 atom per bag thus 16 bags?
AI: Each bag would take 1 second to reach 0.  The total time would be 1 second.
Where did the 4 seconds go?...and what is a "bag"?

what is a “bag”? You used the word first, so you tell us.

although of course the AI is giving you nonsense, your original questions are also nonsense. The naïve answer to your questions are all infinity. At some point you will end up with one atom left, and that atom may take forever to decay.

I suggest asking your physics question directly rather than making it about an AI conversation.

Radioactive decay is a probabilistic process, so you can’t ask how long it takes.

@Ghoster, But of course, you can ask how long it probably takes. OK, You can't ask how long it takes for 16 grams of some substance with half-life 1S to completely decay, but you can ask how long it takes for 16 grams to become one gram, and you can get an extremely accurate prediction (It takes four seconds, plus or minus some immeasurably small error. See Agnius Vasiliauskas's answer for the formula.) But, the smaller the number of atoms, the less accurate the prediction becomes. 16 atoms is a very small number.

The very first answer of AI is wrong. Decay time of a group of atoms is defined by:
$$ \tag 1 \label{eq:1} t=\frac {t_{1/2}}{\ln(2)}\times\ln\left(\frac {N_0}{N}\right),$$
where $N_0$ is the initial atom count in the group, and $N$ - final number of the atom count in the group left. For any fixed $N \geq 1 $, the required decay time for a group is bounded and clearly defined. For example, if you choose $N_0=16$ and number of atoms left $N=8$, then as per $\eqref{eq:1}$ time until such decay happens will be $(1 \ \text{s})/\ln(2)×\ln(16/8) = 1 \ \text{s}$, so to say we got same half-life for these atom types. Hence, this proved that our formula definition $\eqref{eq:1}$ is valid.
Now, what happens when the number of atoms decays from $16$ to $0$? You can look by drawing a chart in Desmos, i.e. function $t(N)=1/\ln(2)\times\ln(16/N)$:

We see that as the atom-decayed count approaches zero, the time required for that asymptotically approaches $\infty$. Or this can be seen if you simply look at the expression $\ln(N_0/0)=\infty$ for any fixed $N_0$, so to say- we have reached a singularity, that is - we will never know when any group of atoms will decay completely.
Hence correct answer of AI to your first question should be "it will require an infinite amount of time", or a better version of it would be "it's impossible to know".
Btw, it's not a surprise that AI's/chatGPT and the like hallucinate A LOT in the physics knowledge area, so you better not ask such types of questions from AI.

"Half-life of one second" does not mean that one half of any given collection of atoms will decay within one second. What it really means is, that if you watch any single atom for one second, the probability of you seeing it decay during that interval is one half.
Agnius Vasiliauskas said,

Decay time of a group of atoms is defined by:
$$t=\frac {t_{1/2}}{\ln(2)}\times\ln\left(\frac {N_0}{N}\right),$$

That claim is practically true when $N$ is some stupendously large number (e.g., the number of atoms in a microgram of matter) but it is not actually true. That formula actually is a statistical prediction.
If you time how long it takes for $N_0-N$ atoms in a collection of $N_0$ to decay, and if you repeat that experiment many times, you'll get a different result from each trial. Agnius Vasiliauskas's formula predicts the average of the results, and if $N$ is stupendously large, the distribution of the results will be so narrow as to be unmeasurable. The prediction will seem to be spot-on. But, when $N_0=16$ the distribution will be very wide,* for $N_0=8$ or 4 or 2 or 1, it's wider still, and in any case, as Agnius pointed out, when $N=0$ it's undefined.
The time it takes for a "bag" of 16 atoms to decay to one atom is not four seconds. It's hard to predict. But, if you do the experiment many times, the average time will be four seconds. The average time it takes for 8 atoms to decay to one is three seconds, but it's even harder to predict. And, if you want to know how long it takes any given number of atoms to decay to zero, that average is undefined. It's impossible to predict.

* I'm not a statistician, and I'm too lazy to do the research to find out how to calculate the probability distribution.
